# how to get latest data for a particular date range for duplicate usrid

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have **2 tables**. One is user details another one is payment table. what i just want to get latest data of that user within a month.

```
$sql="SELECT a.usr_id, a.fname, a.lname, c.user_id, c.payment_dt 
       FROM user_details a 
       INNER JOIN payment c 
               ON a.usr_id = c.user_id 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id, 
                          Max(payment_dt) maxDate 
                   FROM   payment 
                   GROUP  BY user_id) b 
               ON c.user_id = b.user_id 
                  AND c.payment_dt = b.maxdate 
WHERE  c.payment_dt BETWEEN '$start_dt' AND '$end_dt' ";
    $ex = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data['info']  = $ex->result();
```

Comment: what's the issue you are facing?

Comment: do you need multiple results for payment?

Comment: no.i need only latest date payment row for  that user. only a single row. @Gulshan

Comment: I am not getting correct result..means for duplicate userid i m not getting single row.@PathikVejani

Comment: Try `group_by` by `user_id`

Answer (score 0):

Your query will product multiple rows if your have multiple userID. I think you are trying to get a result on a given userID? adding this might help `and a.user_id = '$userID'`

```
$sql="SELECT a.usr_id, a.fname, a.lname, c.user_id, c.payment_dt 
       FROM user_details a 
       INNER JOIN payment c 
               ON a.usr_id = c.user_id 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id, 
                          Max(payment_dt) maxDate 
                   FROM   payment 
                   GROUP  BY user_id) b 
               ON c.user_id = b.user_id 
                  AND c.payment_dt = b.maxdate 
WHERE  c.payment_dt BETWEEN '$start_dt' AND '$end_dt' and a.user_id = '$userID' ";
    $ex = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data['info']  = $ex->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Update you query:

```
$start_dt = '2019-04-01';
$end_dt = '2019-04-06';

$sql="SELECT a.usr_id, a.fname, a.lname, c.user_id, c.payment_dt 
       FROM user_details a 
       LEFT JOIN payment c 
               ON a.usr_id = c.user_id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, 
                          Max(payment_dt) maxDate 
                   FROM   payment 
                   GROUP  BY user_id) b 
               ON c.user_id = b.user_id 
                  AND c.payment_dt = b.maxdate 
WHERE  date(c.payment_dt) BETWEEN '$start_dt' AND '$end_dt' GROUP_BY a.usr_id " ;
```

Hope this will resolve your issue

Comment: sorry.its not returning any data when duplicate users are there in payment table.@Gulshan

Comment: replace `INNER` with `LEFT`

Comment: now working fine After replaced by left  join .thanks @Gulshan

Comment: @SwetalinaRay :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql="SELECT a.usr_id, a.fname, a.lname, c.user_id, max(c.payment_dt) as payment_dt
FROM user_details a 
INNER JOIN payment c ON a.usr_id = c.user_id 
WHERE  c.payment_dt BETWEEN '$start_dt' AND '$end_dt' group by c.user_id";
$ex = $this->db->query($sql);
$data['info']  = $ex->result();
```